# Creating a Dynamic Link Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, html

I am fairly new to java script.
I would like to know how to make a drop down menu in which it will have links as element, but it will change according to what the user inputs.

I am working on a calendar, in which each day there is a different event, and a different link to sign up for that event. My goal is to create a drop down menu that will give the links to sign up for the several events happening on that day. So it will change its content according to which day the user selects. So far, I only see how to create drop down menus with already set links, but I want to have the drop down menu to be able to change the links in the elements, according to what the user chooses.

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
 </ul></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: could you kindly search for a solution and than ask here for the excact problem....your question is to generic that way

Comment: @Cristian what have you tried? Do you have any code that you can post here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how to change links in javascript:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#" id="link1">Menu 1</a></li>
</ul>


<script>
  document.getElementById("link1").setAttribute("href", "https://www.google.com/");
  document.getElementById("link1").innerText = "My New Link"
</script>
```